# How to install Temple Run?

Tags: installation, games

Is there any way I can install and play Temple Run in Ubuntu 13.04. I have basic terminal command skills and don't mind compiling it from source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Imangi Studios website](http://www.imangistudios.com/), Temple Run is not available for Linux.

Temple Run only appears to be available for phones (Windows Phone, iOS devices and Android).

Answer (score 8):

## You can run it through it through the Android emulator

### Create and start Android image

1. Download the Android SDK: https://developer.android.com/sdk/ (Select the **Linux
   32 & 64-bit** entry below **SDK Tools Only**)
2. Start the **Android SDK Manager** (`tools/android` in the downloaded archive)
3. Wait for to download the list of available Android tools
4. Click **Install *#* packages...** in the bottom left corner
5. In the Menu select: **Tools** -> **Manage AVDs**
6. On the left side select: **New...**
7. Enter a name next to **AVD Name**
8. Select a **Device** (**Nexus 4** is fine)
9. Select the first entry next to **Target**
10. Select **CPU/ABI** type **ARM (armeabi-v7a)**
11. Enter at least **200** **MiB** as **SD Card** size
12. Make sure you check **Use Host GPU** next to **Emulation Options**
13. Click **OK**
14. Select your new Android image and click **Start...** on the left-hand side

### Locate game APK

1. In a search engine of your choice search for **Temple Run Android APK**
2. Select the first non-Google result
3. Make sure you can download a file of type **Android Package** for there
4. Copy the URL of the page

### Download and install game

1. In the emulator Android should be running now
2. Select the **Settings** application (just like on the phone)
3. Scroll down until you find **Security** and click on it
4. Check **Unknown Sources** and click **OK** in the warning dialog
5. Press the Home Button on the left-hand side of the emulator
6. Select the **Browser** application
7. Paste the URL from the last step
8. Download the file you have previously found on the website
9. Click on the top panel and pull it across the screen
10. Wait for the download to complete then tap on the entry that says **Download complete**
11. In the installation screen press **Next** on the bottom right of the screen
12. The text of the button will change to **Install** so click it again
13. Wait for the installation to complete
14. Click on the **Open** button on the bottom right of the screen

### You should now have Temple Run running in your Android emulator

Comment: Sorry I accidentally saved too early